# Page resources could not be loaded by Googlebot

Tags: seo, robots.txt, googlebot, google-search-console

When I check my website URL on Google URL inspection tool it shows that page resources could not be loaded i.e image, stylesheet and script files. However, my website is working perfectly on a live server and the website is not rendered properly by Googlebot smartphone. I have tried everything to remove these errors but nothing helped. I have also checked that these resources are not blocked in robots.txt file.

#### Screenshot of page resources error

[image]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now, and finally reached the only solution that has worked for me. In my case, it wasn't a robots.txt problem, as I believe that you've already checked before posting this.

The problem has to do with the number of resources Googlebot is willing to fetch before giving up. If your CSS and JS files are too many, or too big, Googlebot gives up before fetching all of the resources needed to render the page properly.

You can solve it by minifying your files via a server mod, or via plugins like WP Rocket or Autoptimize. If you have too many CSS and JS files and the problem persists after minifying, try combining these files as well by using the same plugins.

Comment: Minifying and Combining CSS worked for me! Thank you!